# How t o remove data in a column other than country name using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[I want to remove the data other than a country name in a column "Country" and I don't know how to proceed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bprs1.png)

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953310/importing-excel-into-panda-dataframe/46953647#46953647)

Comment: Please provide the code as code snipet, and not a link. It'll ease to reproduce the issue.